# magento 2: \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $this->_menu

Tags: magento2, blocks, topmenu

I am currently working on a custom block class that extends `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`

I have the following in my template file that uses my custom block class:

```
<?php $menuTree1 = $block->getMenu()->getChildren() ?>
<?php $counter1 = 1; foreach ($menuTree1 as $item1): ?>
//run foreach statement...
```

In Magento 2.0.7 this worked fine, however after upgrading to 2.1.3 the menu collection seems to return 0 child menu items.  A Zend_Debug on `$block->getMenu()->getChildren()` dump shows this

```
object(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection)#2778 (2) {
  ["_nodes":"Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection":private] => array(0) {
  }
  ["_container":"Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection":private] => object(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node)#2934 (5) {
    ["_parent":protected] => NULL
    ["_tree":protected] => object(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree)#2932 (1) {
      ["_nodes":protected] => object(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection)#2933 (2) {
        ["_nodes":"Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection":private] => array(0) {
        }
        ["_container":"Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection":private] => *RECURSION*
      }
    }
    ["_childNodes":protected] => *RECURSION*
    ["_idField":protected] => string(4) "root"
    ["_data":protected] => array(2) {
      ["outermost_class"] => string(9) "level-top"
      ["children_wrap_class"] => string(7) "submenu"
    }
  }
}
```

The strange part is part is if I overwrite getHtml() in my class as:

```
public function getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
{
    return $this->getMenu()->getChildren();
}
```

My foreach then works properly:

```
<?php $menuTree1 = $block->getHtml() ?>
<?php $counter1 = 1; foreach ($menuTree1 as $item1): ?>
//works properly...
```

This however does not work if I create a custom function the same way I did getHtml()

Block:

```
public function getMyMenuItems()
{
    return $this->getMenu()->getChildren();
}
```

Template:

```
<?php $menuTree1 = $block->getMyMenuItems() ?>
<?php $counter1 = 1; foreach ($menuTree1 as $item1): ?>
//does not work properly
```

Ideally I would like retrieve the _menu object after all the child items have been set.  Does anybody know how to do this or why the collection is only set when calling `getHtml()`?

Comment: I'm not too sure about this, but aren't get and set methods reserved in block classes? getMyMenuItems() is a magic method that would retrieve $block->mymenuitems property. If I'm right that might be part of the problem. Its mentioned in this article http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/

Comment: @jamil still does not work after changing method name to `myMenuItems()`  As I understand magento getters and setters, it will first look to see if function actually exists then if it does not it will try using it as magic methods.